# PLSQL Procedure loop giving unexpected result

Tags: oracle, plsql

In below procedure I am expecting that count will print three times and slno number print last row but I got unexpected result-

A) `count` print 1 and only for single time expecting three times 1,2,3

B) `slno` print 99900004 but expecting 99900002.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE challan_test(seatid  numeric) AS

slno  NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
resultset refcursor;
QUERY VARCHAR(200);
count NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN

QUERY :='Select hstnum_sr_id from hstt_sr_mst where sstnum_type_id = 14 order by 
 hstnum_sr_id desc';

/** Above select statment return 
 99900004
 99900003
 99900002
**/

OPEN resultset FOR QUERY;
 LOOP

        FETCH resultset
         INTO slno;
         count:= count+1;
         dbms_output.put_line('QUERY-- count'||count);
        EXIT;
     END LOOP;
     dbms_output.put_line('QUERY'||slno);

  END
```

In above procedure unable to understand the working of loop or while reading loop their i miss something. I am looking an explanation of loop behavior.

Comment: I retagged your question with `plsql` and `oracle` because this is clearly not Postgres (PL/pgSQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to question why you did it like you did (declaring variables you don't use, procedure has a parameter you don't use, ...), but - here's what's wrong:

- `exit` you used is wrong (should be `exit when resultset%notfound`) and is placed at the wrong place; should immediately follow the `FETCH` command. If it is at the bottom of the loop, counter will increment once more (and you'd get `4` as the result).

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE challan_test (seatid NUMERIC)
  2  AS
  3     slno       NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
  4     resultset  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  5     query      VARCHAR (200);
  6     ccount     NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
  7  BEGIN
  8     query :=
  9        'Select hstnum_sr_id from hstt_sr_mst where sstnum_type_id = 14 order by
 10   hstnum_sr_id desc';
 11
 12     OPEN resultset FOR query;
 13
 14     LOOP
 15        FETCH resultset INTO slno;
 16        EXIT WHEN resultset%NOTFOUND;           --> this, immediately after FETCH
 17        ccount := ccount + 1;
 18        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('QUERY-- count' || ccount);
 19
 20     END LOOP;
 21
 22     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('QUERY' || slno);
 23  END;
 24  /

Procedure created.

SQL> EXEC challan_test(null);
QUERY-- count1
QUERY-- count2
QUERY-- count3
QUERY99900002

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: think I have done blunder..in code..thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

Your EXIT statement is causing the loop to terminate after the first iteration.    change to use a conditional exit:

```
 LOOP    
        FETCH resultset
         INTO slno;
         EXIT WHEN resultset%NOTFOUND;
         count:= count+1;
         dbms_output.put_line('QUERY-- count'||count);

     END LOOP;
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/exit_statement.htm#LNPLS01318) for more details.